# Proving an equivalence relation of a linear transformation.

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $T:R^{n}\rightarrow R^{m}$ be a linear transformation. That is, $T$ is a function that $T(x+y)=T(x)+T(y)$ and $T(cx)=cT(x)$ for all $x, y \in R^{n}$ and $c\in R$. Define a relation on $R^{n}$ by declaring that $x\sim y$ if $T(x-y)$ is the zero vector. Show that this is an equivalence relation.

Don't know how to begin with this...

Comment: Do you know what is an equivalence relation? It satisfies symmetry, reflexivity and transitivity. Surely symmetry must be coming to you. Can you comment, or add in your question, the attempt of symmetry? It's ok if it's wrong then we can correct you.

Answer (score 1):

So for reflexivity you want to show that $T(x-x)=0$. (There should be a property of linear transformations you can use for this).

For symmetry you want to show that if $T(x-y)=0$ then $T(y-x)=0$. (This again follows from another property of linear transformations, possibly different from the first ;))

Finally for transitivity you want to show that if $T(x-y)=0$ and $T(y-z)=0$ then $T(x-z)=0$.